# How to change UITextView text selection to strikethrough without movig the visible textarea

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextview

I uses the following code to make text strikethrough. But after that the visible area moves to the end of the text. But I don't want to move the visible area. How can I do this?

```
        tvText.isScrollEnabled = false

        let rng = tvText.selectedRange
        let text = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: tvText.attributedText)
        let attributes = tvText.attributedText.attributes(at: tvText.selectedRange.lowerBound, effectiveRange: nil)
        if attributes.keys.contains(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle) {
            text.removeAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle, range: tvText.selectedRange)
        } else {
            text.addAttribute(.strikethroughStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue, range: tvText.selectedRange)
        }
        tvText.attributedText = text
        tvText.selectedRange = rng
        tvText.isScrollEnabled = true
```

Many thanks Jens

Comment: have you tried commenting `tvText.selectedRange = rng` in the code above?

Comment: Keep the `tvText.contentOffset` and reset it?

Comment: I tried to use the contentOffset but nothing changes.

Comment: Ok, I tried somehing. When I don't set isScrollEnabled to true at the end of the function everything is fine, but after that I can not scroll the textview. The scroll to the end of the textview happens when I set isScrollEnabled to true. If I set isScrollEnabled to true in another function e.g. by pressing another button also everything is fine. I think there is something in a buffer or stack and will be executed after setting isScrollEnabled to true.